# jquery : Get value from id="foo[1]"?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple  elements that have  ID's (and names) in the form :

```
id="foo[1]"
id="foo[2]"
```

However, I can't seem to get the value back out using:

```
$('#foo[1]').val();
```

What's the correct syntax for accessing these multi-dimensional arrays in Jquery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('[id=foo\[1\]]')` will select those sort of ids

http://jsfiddle.net/UaxC2/

Comment: yes!... but please note also that in this situation it is not good because it's not a valid html. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using id="foo_1" and id="foo_2" instead of the brackets (it will play better).

Then the correct syntax is:   `$('#foo_1').val()`   (you are missing the "#")

Edit:  Looks like your ids aren't valid html:

from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp

> Specifies a unique id for an element.
>   Naming rules:
>
> Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
>   Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z),
>   digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and
>   periods (".") Values are
>   case-sensitive

Answer (score 1):

Square brackets are not legal in IDs. [HTML data types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2) says:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

Also, to select and ID, you need to preface your selector with #, $('#foo').

Comment: It's not legal, but it's used a lot in forms so I can parse it through PHP and access as multidimensional array. The # is there in my original code -> just missed it in re-typing :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#foo[1]').val(); // you missed # which denotes id
```

---

on the other hand, `$('#foo[1]').val();` will not work because brackets is for attributes e.g. `$('#foo[name]')` will get the element with `id` `foo` and with ann attribute name .

Comment: @tster: you'll need to escape: $('#foo\\\[1\\\]').val();

Comment: @Daniel, yes it will work, but I would not suggest it because it's not proper in this situation. id with `[` and `]` is not a valid. ;)

Comment: @Daniel, yes it will work.  Still lets stick with the "write valid html first" line:)

Comment: @Reigel, @tster: then don't make your main argument that it is used for jQuery specific functionality. That is not the issue here :)

Comment: It's not **all** [invalid HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577724/characters-not-allowed-in-dom-ids-by-spec-and-by-browser/3577773#3577773). We are in a transitional phase.

Answer (score 0):

First if you are going to get an item by id , you should add "#" before the id ,

$('#foo[1]').

Second the $() will return all elements that match the supplied pattern , so you will get all elements with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

Using `foo[1]` doesn't really make it a multidimensional array, also you can't explicitly use the [ ] brackets like that, jQuery has a selector that uses that, so you need to use `$('div[id="foo[2]"]')` to get it to work, demo attached. I'd recommend just using `foo1` though.

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/RSRSQ/