# Unable to access dom element using identifier after successfully cloning and appending it

Tags: jquery, dom, cloning

I prepare a clone of a template div, assign it a dynamic ID and append it to DOM, like this:-

```
var chat_window_clone_obj = $('div#chat_window_template').clone();

cloned_element_id = 'chat_window'+dom_id_separator+session_id;
$(chat_window_clone_obj).attr('id',cloned_element_id);
$(chat_window_clone_obj).appendTo("div#chat_windows_holder");
```

But, after that I am not able access the cloned element using its ID (checked in firefox, I am sure this will be the same in all browsers):-

```
$('div#chat_windows_holder').length // comes 0
$('div#chat_windows_holder').removeClass("hidden"); //does not work
```

I am however able to access like this:-

```
$(chat_window_clone_obj).length // works
$(chat_window_clone_obj).removeClass("hidden"); //works
```

What am I missing here? I can see the element appended correctly with the required ID in firefox's HTML tab.

Comment: Why are you wrapping chat_window_clone_obj in $()?

Comment: you shouldn't wrap `chat_window_clone_obj` with `$()` because it will clone the object each time you do so. That means i.e. `$(chat_window_clone_obj).attr('id',cloned_element_id);` should be `chat_window_clone_obj.attr('id',cloned_element_id);`

Comment: Thanks @Tom can you give some explanation or some link explaining that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well guys the problem was that I was using some illegal characters in the dom id which I was assigning to the newly cloned elements.

Something like this -

```
dom_id_separator = '%%--%%'; //  Character % is illegal

var chat_window_clone_obj = $('div#chat_window_template').clone();
cloned_element_id = 'chat_window'+dom_id_separator+session_id;
```

Check [What characters are allowed in DOM IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077084/what-characters-are-allowed-in-dom-ids/1077097#1077097) for list of legal characters.

I was correctly assigning dynamic IDs. I removed the wrapping of `chat_window_clone_obj` with `$()` later.

Answer (score 2):

When you try selecting it by ID, you're getting the original element - as in the first one which matches that ID. [You should not have duplicate IDs in your document](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2). Try this:

```
var chat_window_clone_obj = $("div#chat_window_template").clone();
chat_window_clone_obj.attr("id", "chat_window_clone");
$("#chat_window_clone").doSomething();
```

Comment: I think he's dynamically generating the ID so that's probably not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your not accessing by the correct ID. Is chat_windows_holder the ID of the newly created object?  It doesn't look like it is in your sample code.

What is the value of chat_window_clone_obj? That's the value you should be using in your selector (which is why the second example works).