# Event not firing when OnChange of dropdownlist called

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

On my dropdownlist, I set it up so the onchange should call checkval and pass in the id of element. I just started off with really basic login, but cant even get the alert to display. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
function checkval(id){
    if($('#' + id).val == "Other")
    {
        alert("You Selected Other");
        //other logic will go here
    }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<select name="items1[]" id="items1[]" onchange="checkval(id);">
    <option selected value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>

<select name="items2[]" id="items2[]" onchange="checkval(id);">
    <option selected value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Seems like it fails for id items1[].. So changed your markup bit.. Fixed [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ep3ep/1/) here.

See link for [What characters are allowed in DOM IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077084/what-characters-are-allowed-in-dom-ids)

Change your markup as `onchange="checkval(this.id);"`.

and the script as

```
function checkval(id){
    if($('#' + id).val() == "Other")
    {
        alert("You Selected Other");
        //other logic will go here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<select name="items1[]" id="items1[]" onchange="checkval(this.id);">
```

Or even better, wire up your handler unobtrusively,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".items").change(function(){ 
        checkval(this.id);
    });
});
```

and remove the onchange attributes and add a class:

```
<select name="items1" id="items1" class="items">
    <option selected value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>

<select name="items2" id="items2" class="items">
    <option selected value="">Select One</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: And as others have pointed out, don't forget the parentheses for `.val()` in `checkval()`.

Answer (score 1):

`val` is a function so use it as a function `val()` that will work.

Alernatively you can pass the selected value itself to `chectVal` method.

Change in your markup.

```
<select name="items1[]" id="items1[]" onchange="checkval(this.value);">
<select name="items2[]" id="items2[]" onchange="checkval(this.value);">
```

JS

```
function checkval(value){
    if(value == "Other")
    {
        alert("You Selected Other");
        //other logic will go here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call val with brackets like so:

```
function checkval(id){
    if($('#' + id).val() == "Other")
    {
        alert("You Selected Other");
        //other logic will go here
    }
}
```

As SKS specified, you also have an error in the onchange event, it should be this.id. However, you chould change the code to be a bit easier.

Onchange:

```
<select name="items1[]" id="items1[]" onchange="checkval(this);">
```

And your function:

```
function checkval(el){
    if($(el).val() == "Other")
    {
        alert("You Selected Other");
        //other logic will go here
    }
}
```

Also, do you get any errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

`$('#' + id).val` is a function.
The function is never equal to `"Other"`.

You probably want to *call* the function using parentheses.