# How to select jquery id with double code inside

Tags: jquery

Hi I am facing difficulty in selecting using Jquery
can any body tell me how to select **sellink_0**, id using jquery ?

```
<a     id="\"sellink_0\""     href="\"#\"">
```

Comment: Why are your quotes escaped in your html?

Comment: You should read about what characters are allowed in DOM ID - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077084/what-characters-are-allowed-in-dom-ids

Answer (score 1):

What you have posted is an invalid html.. It is parsed as below,
(as from Firebug and might vary for different browsers)

```
  <a 
  #\="" 
  href="\" 
  sellink_0\="" 
  id="\">
```

Read More here: [What characters are allowed in DOM id's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077084/what-characters-are-allowed-in-dom-ids)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

```
$('#sellink_0')
```