# access an element with '::' in id

Tags: jquery

In following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9sHz/5/

I have an `<li>` with id "test1::newtest"

When I press button - enable 'Li Point1' the `<li>` element Li Point1 remains un draggable but if I remove the :: from the id as in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q9sHz/6/
It becomes draggable when I click the button.

Is having ':' within an ID not allowed?

Comment: [Addressed in jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F). You might also do an attribute selector for the ID attribute. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/26fzz/)

Comment: Similar post and answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077084/what-characters-are-allowed-in-dom-ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to quote [the jQuery-FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F):

> The colon (":") and period (".") are problematic within the context of a jQuery selector because they indicate a pseudo-class and class, respectively.
>
> In order to tell jQuery to treat these characters literally rather than as CSS notation, they must be "escaped" by placing two backslashes in front of them.

as you can see, you have to escape the colons in the jquery-selector using `\\`. see [this working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9sHz/11/).

Answer (score 3):

jQuery uses the colon to build selectors. For instance `$('.class:checked')` or `$('.class:hidden')`

You'll need to escape the colon like this

```
test1\\:\\:newtest
```

**From jQuery FAQs**

> Because jQuery uses CSS syntax for selecting elements, some characters are interpreted as CSS notation. For example, ID attributes, after an initial letter (a-z or A-Z), may also use periods and colons, in addition to letters, numbers, hyphens, and underscores (see W3C Basic HTML Data Types). The colon (":") and period (".") are problematic within the context of a jQuery selector because they indicate a pseudo-class and class, respectively.
>
> In order to tell jQuery to treat these characters literally rather than as CSS notation, they must be "escaped" by placing two backslashes in front of them.

```
// Does not work
$("#some:id")

 // Works!
$("#some\\:id")
```

[How do I select an element by an ID that has characters used in CSS notation?](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_select_an_element_by_an_ID_that_has_characters_used_in_CSS_notation.3F)

Answer (score 1):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/Q9sHz/12/

You need to escape these special characters `\\:\\:` will do the trick for you.

**code**

```
// when button clicked ...
$('#enable').click(function() {
    // also enable li tag with id test1
    $('#test1\\:\\:newtest').draggable('enable');
});

​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// set draggable functionality to all li tags
$('.myLi').draggable();
// disable all li tags which have the class disable
$('.disable').draggable('disable');

// when button clicked ...
$('#enable').click(function() {
    // also enable li tag with id test1
    $('#test1newtest').draggable('enable');
});
```

Comment: How does this address the question?

Comment: you should read the question before posting an answer. as user470184 noticed himself, striping out the colons works - the question is how to do this _with_ colons.