# How do I force the ID for an input field in my form_helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I would like the `id` for my input to be `user[email]` and not `user_email`. But everything I try doesn't work.

I am using the latest version of Devise for these gems.

This is my form:

```
  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :class => "send-with-ajax", :url => user_registration_path(resource), :validate => true, :html => { :id => 'user_new' }) do |f| %>
                    <div class="six columns alpha"> 
      <%= f.text_field :email, :id => 'user[email]', :placeholder => "your-email@address.com", :input_html => {:autofocus => true}, :validate => true %>
                        </div>              
                        <div class="three columns sign-up alpha">
      <%= f.submit :label => "Submit", :value => "Sign Me Up!" %>
                          <div class="ajax-response"><%= devise_error_messages! %></div>
      </div>
  <% end %>
```

This is the HTML produced:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" class="formtastic user" data-validate="true" id="user_new" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="khstyw72jj44kkhaskdya3hkb3ba3lkxmw4=" /></div>
                        <div class="six columns alpha"> 
              <input data-validate="true" id="user_email" input_html="{:autofocus=&gt;true}" name="user[email]" placeholder="your-email@address.com" size="30" type="text" />
                            </div>              
                            <div class="three columns sign-up alpha">
              <input label="Submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Sign Me Up!" />
                              <div class="ajax-response"></div>
              </div>
</form>
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I thought specifying id like you did would override the default, guess not. So I can't help you - but wanted to point out `input_html => {:autofocus => true}` is not working as you expect either. I would tend to live with the default rails naming here, fighting rails on this stuff can hurt.

Comment: What does it do? How do I force a re-load locally? I took out `:input_html =>` and it doesn't reflect when I refresh my page.

Answer (score 2):

ID cannot contain square brackets, so it might be the cause, that Rails changes it.

See: 
[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)
and [What characters are allowed in DOM IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077084/what-characters-are-allowed-in-dom-ids)

Comment: Actually, I just tried it again and it seems to have changed it. So it seems brackets actually do work.

Comment: Still brackets are not valid chars in the ID, so it might be reasonable not to use them.

Comment: Yeh, I am not going to use them...but I was just debugging another issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems I had to restart my server to get the form_helper changes to be reflected.

So `:id => user[email]` does work.