# jQuery .val() returns undefined at complex id

Tags: jquery, undefined

I have two hidden input fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="institut" id="institut" value="blablub" />
<input type="hidden" name="institut[0]" id="institut[0]" value="moreblablub" />
```

I have this debugging code:

```
console.log("#institut: " + $("#institut").val());
console.log("#institut[0]: " + $("#institut[0]").val());
```

And I get this console output:

```
#institut: blablub
#institut[0]: undefined
```

I trid to escape the square brackets with backslashes but that did not change anything. Is there a way to get hold of complex ID's?

Comment: Try `$("#institut\\[0\\]").val()`

Comment: Actually, it's not allowed to use `[` and `]` characters in ID identifier. So even if you fix this code, it might got broken someday. Why don't just use another separator, like '-' or '_'?

Comment: @raina77ow Could you provide a source? I haven't found any such restrictions in the HTML standard.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1077111/561731

Comment: @Neal That answer cites the HTML 4 standard. HTML 4 was an application of SGML. The title of the cited section is "SGML Basic Types", and in it, the ID token is specified. However, HTML is no longer an application of SGML, so those rules no longer apply. I've been searching in the HTML Living Standard, and the [corresponding section](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-id-attribute) states that the value of the "id" attribute must contain at least one character, and no space characters. I haven't found any other restrictions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should **not** be using non alphanumeric characters for an id.

But if you do you can do:

```
var element = document.getElementById("institut[0]");
var $element = $(element);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/sWnJN/

Or

```
var $element = $("#institut\\[0\\]");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/sWnJN/1/

Or even:

```
var $element = $("[id='institut[0]']");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/sWnJN/2/

Comment: I don't think there exists `getElementsById`. You are probably confusing it with `getElementById`, which will not be able to fetch that id, since it's invalid.

Comment: @João sorry I typed an extra `s`

Comment: That was fast and the second part of your question solved the problem.  Thanks a lot. - First part of you answer. I keep that in mind for future projects.

Comment: @João that selector works perfectly fine ^_^ see the Demo :-)

Comment: @Neal - the selector ... should have thought of that :-)

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape the brackets:

```
$( '#institut\\[0\\]' ).val()
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Qsagn/

Brackets are special characters in CSS - they define attribute selectors. You need to double-escape the brackets. A single escape `\[` is not enough, since the `\` character is a special character in string literals, so you need `\\` in order to escape the `\` character, so that it is interpreted as a literal character.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `document.getElementsByName("institut[0]")[0].value`.