# Hide select box in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am trying to hide a drop-down using JavaScript. The following code I have gotten to work in Firefox and Chrome but testing in IE 8 it does not work.

```
<select name="month" id="month" onchange="monthselector_changed(this)">
  <option  value="1">
        Jan</option>
  <option  value="2">
        Feb</option>
  <option  value="3">
        Mar</option>
  <option  value="4">
        Apr</option>
  <option  value="5">
        May</option>
  <option  value="6">
        Jun</option>
  <option  value="7">
        Jul</option>
  <option  value="8">
        Aug</option>
  <option  value="9">
        Sep</option>
  <option  value="10">
        Oct</option>
  <option selected value="11">
        Nov</option>
  <option  value="12">
        Dec</option>
  </select>
```

I then hide it using the following code

```
document.getElementById("month").style.display = 'none';
```

Just for clarfication I am trying to hide then entire select box not an option.

Comment: You should REALLY look into a framework like JQuery.

Comment: It works here.. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/772Z2/1) IE8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is invalid in an ID field, so that's probably messing up IE while other browers are being more "relaxed" about the rule.

See this thread for details:
[What characters are allowed in DOM IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077084/what-characters-are-allowed-in-dom-ids)

Edit:  I see you're passing in `this` to a function call.  You can use `this` to do the toggling without an ID.  For example:

http://jsbin.com/acisof/1/edit

```
function monthselector_changed(elem)
{
    elem.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: the ID is not causing the problem, for testing I changed it to month and did document.getElementById("month"). I have updated the above question to show this.

Comment: Then check the JS console for errors. F12. My guess is there's an error.

Comment: no errors, was something odd about how .jsp was working with the page. setting it to style.visibility = 'hidden'; worked for IE. In the console I actually just ran document.getElementById("month").style.display = 'none';. This caused it to disappear but the second you clicked on the page it became visible again.  Only happened in IE, setting the visibility to hidden stayed hidden.