# Different behaviour of jQuery-code in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: jquery, each

I struggled with strange case.
1. The same page is opened and debugged in Chrome and Firefox.
2. Code is:

```
$("ul[id^='_'").each(function(){
         // some actions which work good in Chrome
});
```

3. While debugging I figured out that problem is in `$("ul[id^='_'")`
4. Trying to execute this in Chrome console I get:

[image]

that is OK and I expect. However the same code in Firefox 25 returns me the follow:

[image]

That is empty object, which obviously not.
So what's difference between this code in two browsers?
I suspect that problem might be in the cyrillic value of id-attribute, but it successfully works and IE and Chrome , and falls in Firefox and Mozilla ?

Please, help me to fix .

**UPD:** http://jsfiddle.net/jeston/WEm78/

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: i think that id field cannot start with anything else other than letter. Try to rename your ul id field to something else (not start with symbol/letter) and check again your 2 browsers

Comment: You made a typo : `ul[id^='_']` Seems chrome automatically fixes this for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1077111/214892) as to what to use for an ID.

In short, issue is a HTML ID field can start only with a letter, no numbers or special characters.

For example, these are valid IDs

```
hello
hello_1
hello_world_1
dropdown
```

These aren't

```
1_dropdown
$34_element
```

Comment: A id can start with a underscore, so that wasn't the problem.

Comment: actually the source you quote is from an old answer, referring to a [html4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name), it isn't true in [html5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 3):

is that maybe wrong:

```
$("ul[id^='_']").each(function(){
         console.log(this)
});
```

//ul[id^='_'**]** <----

Comment: yes, you're right. I voted, however I think that answer about ID attroibute in HTML makes code more relaible.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution

```
var $result = $('ul').filter(function(){
    return this.id.charAt(0) === '_';
});

console.log($result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2enJ3/