# Jquery Handing special charcters in ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating an HTML from the json response and this can be any data.

Id can be anything like

```
Blue & White Dress
Black Dress
```

I tried like

```
$("['id="+dressId+"']").prop('checked', false);
```

But still jquery is throwing an error saying that

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ['id=Blue & White Dress']
```

Can you help on this?

Thanks ,Inadvance.

Comment: I think you might have your quote marks all over the place, try this. $('[id="'+dressId+'"]')

Comment: You have whitespace in your id. You can't : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @MCMXCII,Thanks for your reply.can you add this as an answer.So that I can accept the answer.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have your quote marks all over the place, try this. $('[id="'+dressId+'"]')

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 does not suppor id's with any space and also some special characters are not valid. You'll need to change you id for instance `'Blue_White_Dress'` that it's valid.

Also check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028211/what-is-the-standard-naming-convention-for-html-css-ids-and-classes), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077084/what-characters-are-allowed-in-dom-ids).

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the id you can

```
$("#"+showdiv+"").show();
```

where showdiv is the dynamic id that you have