# After clicking on the back button, reset button not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a search form which have two buttons: the search button and the reset button. the reset button works before going to the next page but returning to the page (using the back button), the reset button no longer works. The function for the reset button is below. Can you help me to solve this issue. Thanks.

```
$(function() {
    $("###frmName#-btnReset").click(function(event) {

        $("form[name='#frmName#']")[0].reset();

    });
});
```

Comment: Actually why do you need here event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

Comment: Hello, if I remove these two lines of code, it still not working. I put an alert in the function, it's working but i don't why the .reset() function is not working.

Comment: Try to use type="reset" in your html instead reset form using jquery

Comment: ok, i tried the type='reset' in my html, it's still not working. However, it works on first loading of the page but when going back to the page again (clicking on the back button), it no longer works.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not symantically correct to have number signs `#` in an `id` or `name` attribute. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077084/what-characters-are-allowed-in-dom-ids

Comment: hello, the sign # is because i'm using cold fusion. it works at first load of the page