# How to hide item in html with jquery using variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to use this simple script to hide some element by ID, i have the id in a variable but it doesn't work..
this is the code:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
function filter(id_get) {
  $(".product").each(function(index) {
    var f = this.id;
    if (!f.includes(id_get)) {
      var hash = "#";
      var cmp = hash.concat(f);
      $(cmp).attr("display", "none");
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

if i do a `console.log(cmp)` it displays correct product id to remove, but it doesn't hide the div.

i've also tried `$(cmp).hide`

Comment: Don't know if that's the only problem, but setting display `attr` to none will do nothing (there is no `display` attribute into the element). `display` is a css property. In order to hide your elements with jQuery, ou can use `$(cmp).css("display","none");` or `$(cmp).hide()` (with parentheses).

Comment: you can simplify it to `$(".product [id$=" + id_get + "]").hide()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are attempting to change an attribute directly. `display` is not an attribute. `style` is an attribute. You can change the  `display` property of the `style` attribute. Change `$(cmp).attr("display","none");` to:

```
$(cmp).css("display", "none");
```

Or, you can just use the built in jQuery `hide` function. Change `$(cmp).attr("display","none");` to:

```
$(cmp).hide();
```

In context:

```
function filter(id_get){
    $( ".product" ).each(function( index ) {
        var f = this.id;
        if(!f.includes(id_get)){
          var hash = "#";
          var cmp = hash.concat(f);
          $(cmp).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Are you sure your id's match up?

Comment: If you post more of your html code, we might be able to see what else could be going on. As it is now, we're driving blind. My answer could be only part of the solution. There could be something else going on as well.

Comment: the problem was that i had a class named "A+++",why i can't?

Comment: Not sure what you mean there. Can't what?

Comment: <div id="A+++_OT"> this doesn't work, <div id="_OT"> this works

Comment: I see. That's expected. You can't use `+` in the id. Only letters, numbers, dashes, etc. Check this for a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077084/what-characters-are-allowed-in-dom-ids