# Generated id in React returning error when using react-portal-toolip

Tags: reactjs, template-literals

I have a chat box for a stream and I want to have react-portal-tooltips have a dropdown to show a users information when I select their name.

**Visual**

[image]

The way that react-portal-tooltips knows which dom element to put a tooltip under is by taking a element id. When I hardcode the id in everything works just fine. However I can't hard code because as you know chat items are generated dynamically. So I've been trying to create a id dynamical threw the use of props. When I do this however it returns with this error. 
[image]

Now this only happens when I use variables in the name so the props. I've checked the values for what the output is and they are correct and what I want. This is why I'm confused because if the value is correct but it treats the string as if it is an incorrect data type.

**Component Code (React.js)**

*This is the component for each chat item individually that gets generated.*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import ToolTip from 'react-portal-tooltip';

class ChatItem extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isTooltip: false
        };
    }

    render(props) {
        const { isTooltip, stampId } = this.state;
        const { id, userColor, time, name, message } = this.props;

        return (
            <Container>
                <Content id={`${id}_${name}`}>
                    <Stamp
                        userColor={userColor}
                        onClick={() => this.setState(prevState => ({isTooltip: !prevState.isTooltip}))}>
                        ({time}) {name}
                    </Stamp>: {message}
                </Content>

                <ToolTip
                    active={isTooltip}
                    position="bottom"
                    arrow="center"
                    parent={`#${id}_${name}`}
                    style={userTooltip}
                >
                    <h1>{name}</h1>
                </ToolTip>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default ChatItem;
```

Oh and before anyone asks the onClick method is correct in fact EVERYTHING works perfectly when I hard code the ID my issue lies inside the ToolTip component with the parent attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is perfectly clear:

> `#10_Torrent45 is not a valid selector`

Valid ID selectors: [What characters are allowed in DOM IDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077084/what-characters-are-allowed-in-dom-ids)

TLDR: cannot start with a number.

Fix:

```
<Content id={`content_${id}_${name}`}>
```

Comment: Wait id's cant start with numbers? I guess I've never run into that problem before....

Comment: think of ID's like JavaScript variables...  `var 10_Torrent = 'foo'`, then it makes more sense